# Work done in rotating a dipole in NON uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, torque, dipole

I understand that the torque on a dipole due to a non uniform electric field is given by the same expression as that of in a uniform electric field i.e. pEsinθ. Now,how do you calculate the work done in rotating this dipole. I tried to integrate pEsinθ.dθ from limits say θ1 to θ2. But since the electric field is not uniform how do you go about integrating the thing, or is E to be taken constant?

I was trying to calculate the potential energy of a dipole in a NON UNIFORM field and got stuck here. Also, since the force acting is non zero, work would have to be done in keeping the dipole at its position, apart from the work done in rotating it, how do you calculate that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Work done in rotating electric dipole in uniform field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374959/work-done-in-rotating-electric-dipole-in-uniform-field)

Comment: Went through it before asking, it's about unfirom electric field. The integration for work there is with the electric field uniform, but that's what I'm asking, how do you integrate when the field is non uniform.